# Send data over voice call

Tags: cdma

Is it possible to send some binary data over voice call? i.e. "client" calls "server's" number and sends encoded data as sound? And what estimated speed can be achieved using CDMA?

Comment: For small amounts of data just use DTMF, otherwise look at the various modem standards.

Comment: "Is it possible?" is not an acceptable question here. Possible answers can be "Yes, it is possible" or "No, it is not possible" with no other content, which would be of no benefit to you or anyone else. Questions here should be specific, and ask actual questions that can be answered in a meaningful fashion that will be of use to future readers here.

Comment: @KenWhite In fact it is of benefit to someone else..

Comment: @abdellahmansur: No, it is not **here** at SO. The question does not meet the minimum quality guidelines here, where questions are supposed to be **specific questions about actual problems you are facing**. "Is it possible?" is definitely not **specific**.

Comment: I'm very interested that where did you ended up after this obviously not correctly asked and answered question , actually now I have itch to do this stuff on my own any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes.   It's called in-band signaling, but it's tricky.  A lot can go wrong as those bits fly through the phone, the voice switches, compressors, etc.   (Binary data really doesn't like that stuff -- there's no 0.8 bit :-) ) We used to do stuff just like this back in the mid-90s to allow you to use a modem on a cellular voice channel.   DId it work?   Somewhat -- but the baud rates were poor and roaming and various other items made it even worse.

Comment: the 0.8 problem is why we have Digital Signal Processing.